# CakePHP 2.7.1 unauthorizedRedirect

Tags: cakephp

In my *AppController* I have this code for the component

```
    public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            ),
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'member',
                'action' => 'index'
            )
        ),
        'Session',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar'
    );
```

So, `unauthorizedRedirect` is working fine. I tried to type the *URL* the user has no access to and fortunately, I am redirected to `'localhost/appname/member/'.`

My concern is that, this only applies to one type of logged in user.

Let us say a logged in user tried to access `localhost/appname/admin/add_post/`. Since only admins have access to that page, the user will be redirected to `localhost/appname/member/`. What if it's an admin who accessed an *unauthorized* page? Of course, that admin will have to redirected somewhere, but not to `localhost/appname/member/`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: You can use cakephp's default ACL(Access Controll List) or you can make your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so after several hours of researching and stuff I was able to come up with a solution.

This is the code for the AppCntroller:

```
     public $components = array(
        'Acl',
        'Auth' => array(
            'authorize' => array(
                'Actions' => array('actionPath' => 'controllers')
            ),
            'unauthorizedRedirect' => false
        ),
        'Session',
        'DebugKit.Toolbar'
    );
```

What this does is rather than redirecting the user to another page, it will just show 'error400.ctp'.

Now, we don't want to show the default CakePHP error layout so we still have to edit it or make a custom one.

Create a new file under 'View/Layouts/your_error_file.ctp'. After that, go to 'View/Errors/error_file.ctp' and paste the following code:

```
$this->layout = 'your_error_file'
```

Comment: I can't understand how this answers what you have asked

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are many ways. You are already using the ACL which is one way. Or another "lazy" way to do this is to use the beforeFilter method inside the AppController.